# How to rotate text in a spreadsheet cell using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache, excel, api, spreadsheet

How can I rotate the text within an HSSFCell class of Apache POI?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use HSSFCellStyle, that class has a method called setRotation(short rotation) which will rotate the text.  All you do is apply the cell style to a cell:

```
HSSFCellStyle myStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
myStyle.setRotation((short)90);

HSSFCell c = row.createCell(columnNumber);
c.setCellStyle(myStyle);
```

Comment: The int parameter in setRotation should be cast to short.

Answer (score 2):

```
CellStyle cssVertical = wb.createCellStyle();
cssVertical.setFont(f);
cssVertical.setRotation((short)90);
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(1);
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);

XSSFCellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
cs.setRotation((short) 90);              // set text rotation
cs.getStyleXf().setApplyAlignment(true); // <<< Important

cell.setCellValue("Vertical Text");
cell.setCellStyle(cs);

workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("out.xlsx"));
```

Apache POI 3.17, need to manually add  alignment="true" attribute in cellXfs section.